# Parallel.ForEach how to know at which item ? - which loop?

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

Example

```
  var options = new ParallelOptions()
  {
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
  };

  List<string> lstAllUrls = File.ReadAllLines("myList.txt").ToList<string>();

  Parallel.ForEach(lstAllUrls, options, myFunctionThatFetchPage);
```

Now this works perfectly fine. What I want to know is: How can I tell at which iteration I currently am. I mean lets say my list has 100000 URLs. It starts fetching them. But I also want to print on  the screen which URL is getting fetched at the moment.

How can I do that? How can I tell at which item of the given list the loop currently is?

Comment: You should do that in `myFunctionThatFetchPage`. For example at the start of the function you might add the url to a list, and at the end you'd remove it. Note that depending on what you're updating you might need to call back to the UI thread when you update your list.

Comment: you can't know the order in which the url's will be processed, thay will be run in paralell.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett thanks that is an option. I wonder are there any index like in a for loop.

Comment: @Jodrell the only think i want to know is like it is processing ith of the url at the url list. I mean foreach must be having an index to know which item to process next.

Comment: It might make sense to report progress, rather than the index(es) it's currently processing. i.e. in your function just increment a counter and display that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) of `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Action<TSource, ParallelLoopState, long> body
)
```

It will pass the current element index to your delegate in the third parameter.

Comment: thanks for answer but i can't figure out how to use this with my code.

Comment: myFunctionThatFetchPage should be declared as `void myFunctionThatFetchPage (string p1, ParallelLoopState p2, long p3)`

Comment: that tells you where the index of the item in the list. Not necessarily the order in which they are processed.

Comment: thanks alex now that makes more sense. so p3 is the index number or p2 ?

Comment: or using lambda: `Parallel.ForEach(lstAllUrls, options, (x, y, i) => { ... });`. Inside the braces the `x` is your item (the url) and `i` is the current index.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG , p3 is the index. If you can't modify your method, you can use the advice from Tallmaris

Answer (score 5):

Since the items are supplied to your URL-processing delegate in parallel, it may "see" your list indexes out of sequence, i.e. items will higher indexes would be supplied for processing ahead of items with lower indexes. This is usually not what you want for your `"M out of N"` messages.

One way to fix this would be using [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) on a counter that you set up separately from the `ForEach` mechanism:

```
private int count;
...
void MyForEachDelegate(string urlStr) {
    ...
    int pos = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    if ((pos-1) % 1000 == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing URL number {0}", pos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Parallel.ForEach is like it's cousin foreach - not good at knowing which iteration it's at. You could use Parallel.For instead and use the loop variable to tell the position. In general keep in mind that anything that you do in the loop which accesses shared resources may reduce the degree of parallelism, so don't go overboard with progress bar code or the like.